# How to bring Image in front while scaling it using animation in WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, user-controls, wpf-controls, expression-blend

I was working with blend, i stuck in situation where i have to bring the image in front while scaling it.

Scenario:

I have `ScrollViewer` inside that I have a main `Grid` containing other various controls like `ListBox`, `Grid`, `StackPanel` etc. In my screen at the bottom, I have a `Grid` containing a `StackPanel`, and inside that `StackPanel`, I have a few images

My requirement is when the user clicks on the image at the bottom, the image should enlarge and must be placed in the center of the screen and top of all controls like as we do in any photoviewer. I created a `StoryBoard` and used `Render` and `Scale` transform to bring the image in center and increase its size, but when I scale the image, half of the image gets behind the other control on the screen. I tried using `ZIndex`, but it did not work.

I want when the Image Scales it should stay at the top of all controls, should not get behind any control while scaling.

I hope I stated my problem clearly in case any one did not understand please comment.

Can someone tell me how can I bring the Image on top while Scaling using storyboard! Below is the screenshot of my screen where you can see half image below other controls:

[image: screen shot]